# Suppose $f(x)$ has continuous $(n+1)$-th derivative over $[a,b]$, and $f(a)=f'(a)=\cdots=f^{(n)}(a)=0$, prove an upper bound for $|f(x)|$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

**Problem**: Suppose $f(x)$ has continuous $(n+1)$-th derivative over $[a,b]$, and $f(a)=f'(a)=\cdots=f^{(n)}(a)=0$, prove that
$$
\max\limits_{a\le x\le b}|f(x)|\le\frac{(b-a)^n}{n!}\int_a^b|f^{(n+1)}(x)|\mathrm{d}x
$$

**My attempt**: Clearly this problem has something to do with Taylor expansion. We take the Taylor expansion of $f(x)$ at $x=a$:
$$
f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+\cdots+\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi)}{(n+1)!}(x-a)^{n+1}
$$
where $\xi\in(a,x)$.

Also, since $(b-a)^n$ appears in the formula, we consider
$$
f(b)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(\xi_b)}{(n+1)!}(b-a)^{n+1}
$$
where $\xi_b\in(a,b)$.

But I don't know how to deal with $\max\limits_{a\le x\le b}|f(x)|$. I can't think of a formula containing $\max |f(x)|$. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Taylor's theorem with the [*integral remainder:*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder)
$$
f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)+\cdots+\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n+\int_a^x \frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^n \, dt
$$
so that in your case
$$
|f(x)| = \left| \int_a^x \frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!}(x-t)^n\, dt\right| 
\le \frac{1}{n!}\int_a^x |f^{(n+1)}(t)| \cdot (x-t)^n\, dt \\
\le \frac{1}{n!}\int_a^b |f^{(n+1)}(t)| \cdot (b-a)^n\, dt
= \frac{(b-a)^n}{n!}\int_a^x |f^{(n+1)}(t)| \, dt
$$

For a proof of Taylor's theorem with the integral remainder, see for example  [Derivation for the integral form of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Derivation_for_the_mean_value_forms_of_the_remainder), it is essentially repeated integration by parts.

Comment: A proof I know is simple. It relies on consecutive integrations by parts. See [this](http://www.math.umd.edu/~immortal/MATH410/lecturenotes/ch8-5.pdf)

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: Thanks for the reference. The Wikipedia article contains also a proof (I have added the link to the answer), which looks similar at first sight.

Comment: Right. I couldn't spot that as it is located at the very end of the article.